# Encrypt/Decrypt ListBox items to Base64 or TripleDES

Tags: vb.net, encryption, base64, tripledes

I want to encrypt and decrypt my ListBox text strings into Base64 or TripleDES.
I tried using TripleDES, but I don't know how to make it work with ListBoxes.
Here's the code I used:

TripleDES Class:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography                                                                         Public NotInheritable Class PassEncryption
Private TripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
Private Function TruncateHash(
ByVal key As String,
ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim keyBytes() As Byte =
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
    Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)
    ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
    Return hash
End Function
Sub New(ByVal key As String)
    TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize \ 8)
    TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize \ 8)
End Sub
Public Function EncryptData(
ByVal plaintext As String) As String
    Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte =
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
        TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(),
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
End Function
Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String
    Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
        TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(),
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
    decStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
End Function
End Class
```

And actually use:
Encrypt:

```
        For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items`
        Dim EncodePassword As String = item
        Dim key As String = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
        Dim wrapper As New PassEncryption(key)
        Dim cipherText As String = wrapper.EncryptData(EncodePassword)
TextBox2.Text = cipherText
Using SW1 As New IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\Encoded.txt", True)

        SW1.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)

    End Using
```

Decrypt:

```
Dim cipherText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Encoded.txt")
        Dim key As String = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
        Dim wrapper As New PassEncryption(key)
            Dim DecodedPassword As String = wrapper.DecryptData(cipherText)
            TextBox2.Text = DecodedPassword
```

So, how can I encrypt/decrypt ListBoxes using this or other algorithm (p.e Base64)?

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, its an encoding.

Comment: Anyway, how can I do that?